# Azure Maps - Change the Map center on an event click on another html element

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I am building SPA react page with azure maps control. I have a sort of left navigation control which represents a list of offices that we have across the globe.

I load the maps with a default center focused on North America, now i have to change the maps center when some one click on an office location in Europe in left nav.

Is there a sample around that, i tried changing the map center in the option but the map never recenter.

Comment: Just found the answer; after a bit of digging. Use cameraoptions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.cameraoptions?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also find these sample useful: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Page%20through%20POI%20results

https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Interactive%20Search%20Quickstart

Comment: Thanks rbrundritt!! One more questions on maps. I need to add a html marker now for buildings and on click of it, launch a popup that displays site specific information. I need to pass site details to the popup so i can fetch the site specific info, for that i need to capture the map data point that was clicked but html marker click args is not having any reference of the datapoint that was clicked. In my case the datapoint has a id that i can use to fetch site specific details and pass on to popup control.

Comment: When you create your marker, simply attach your data to the marker using a custom property. For example: `var marker = new atlas.HtmlMarker(); marker.properties = yourDataObject;` the HTML marker is returned in the event handler, so from there you simply grab the property you attached.

Answer (score 0):

In the left navigation control, I believe you have a `dropdown` or an `input` element and trying to pass the values to the Map and update the Map center accordingly.

In that case, I would suggest to try the below JS function `onChange` / `OnClick`

```js
//Trigger the below function onClick or onchange actions
function updateMapCenter(coordinateValues){
                map.setCamera({
                center: coordinateValues,
                zoom: 7      
            });
```